# PHP include pages error

Tags: php, include

Still trying to get how PHP works :)
Kindly help me with one solution & idea, here is when i'm using:

```
<?php
    $content = array(
        'id01'=>'sub_id01.php',
        'id02'=>'sub_id02.php'
    );
    if(in_array($_GET['show'], array_keys($content))) {
        include($content[$_GET['show']]);
    } else {
        include('sub_id00.php');
    }
?>
```

and:

```
<?php
$content = array(
    'id00'=>'N/A',
    'id01'=>'ID01',
    'id02'=>'ID02',
);
if(!empty($_GET['show']) && isset($content[$_GET['show']])) {
    echo $content[$_GET['show']];
} else {
     echo $content['id00'];
}
?>
```

Where first example includes pages and second includes simple code inside ''

Problem is that if there is no ID set (index.php) ut shows default page/code. And if wrong ID set, it'll also show default page/code.
How to update it so without any ID set it would show default page and if some wrong ID set, it would show some error page/code?
Cheers!

**UPDATE!**

After a while reqding i've updated it with:

```
<?php
    $content = array(
        'id01'=>'sub_id01.php',
        'id02'=>'sub_id02.php'
    );

    if (in_array($_GET['show'], array_keys($content)))
    {
        include($content[$_GET['show']]);
    }

    elseif (isset($_GET['show']))
    {
        include('sub_error.php');
    }
    else {
        include('sub_id00.php');
    }
?>
```

And:

```
<?php
    $content = array(
        'error'=>'error msg',
        'id00'=>'N/A',
        'id01'=>'ID01',
        'id02'=>'ID02',
    );

    if(!empty($_GET['show']) && isset($content[$_GET['show']]))
    {
        echo $content[$_GET['show']];
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['show']))
    {
        echo $content['error'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo $content['id00'];
    }
?>
```

:)

Comment: You mention ID, but don't indicate where in your code you are looking for the ID. Do you mean `$_GET['show']`? You need to specify.

Comment: "problem is it does X, how make to make it do X"? huh? if it shows the default page when a wrong or no ID is provided, and it does that, then what's the problem?

Comment: i mean i have (id01) & (id02) set, so whem i'm using (index.php?showid01) or (index.php?showid02) i'm getting those ID pages/code but if there is none ID (index.php) it shows default page, same page is if some one will choose some wrong ID which is not set, like (index.php?somewrongid)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $content = array(
        'id01'=>'sub_id01.php',
        'id02'=>'sub_id02.php'
    );
    if (isset($_GET['show']))
    {
        if (array_key_exists($_GET['show'], $content)) 
        { 
            //$_GET id is set and it exists in content
            include($content[$_GET['show']]);
        }
        else
        {
            //$_GET id is set but does not exist in content
            //include whatever page you have for a wrong id here
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        //else no $_GET was set 
        //include default page
    }
```

Comment: It is not. This checks for the $_GET value, which you don't do. When there is no $_GET value it returns false and includes your basic 'sub_id00' file.

Comment: But it also includes same page 'sub_id00.php' if it's (index.php) or some invalid ID set, like (index.php?somewrongid)

Comment: You wanted to show your default page, I assume that is sub_id00?

Comment: No, i mean i have (id01) & (id02) set, so when i'm using (index.php?showid01) or (index.php?showid02) i'm getting those ID pages/code but if there is none ID (index.php) it shows default page, same page is if some one will choose some wrong ID which is not set, like (index.php?somewrongid) ... so i really need to make one default page & page if wrong ID is set, like (index.php?somewrongid) ? :)

Comment: @Naruto, what u mean?